# Add an image in a specific position in the document (.docx)?

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, python-docx

I use Python-docx to generate Microsoft Word document.The user want that when he write for eg: "Good Morning every body,This is my %(profile_img)s do you like it?"
in a HTML field, i create a word document and i recuper the picture of the user from the database and i replace the key word %(profile_img)s by the picture of the user **NOT at the END OF THE DOCUMENT**. With Python-docx we use this instruction to add a picture:

```
document.add_picture('profile_img.png', width=Inches(1.25))
```

The picture is added to the document but the problem that it is added at the end of the document.
Is it impossible to add a picture in a specific position in a microsoft word document with python? I've not found any answers to this in the net but have seen people asking the same elsewhere with no solution.

Thanks (note: I'm not a hugely experiance programmer and other than this awkward part the rest of my code will very basic)

Comment: What if you first add the part of the text left to the key phrase, then add the image, and then add the rest of the text? Have you tried this?

Comment: Hello Lenz, Yes i have tried it but the result is the text "Good Morning every body,This is my" in the first line ," do you like it" in the second line and the picture at the end of the document

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Quoting [the python-docx documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/shapes.html):

> The Document.add_picture() method adds a specified picture to the end of the document in a paragraph of its own. However, by digging a little deeper into the API you can place text on either side of the picture in its paragraph, or both.

When we "dig a little deeper", we discover the [`Run.add_picture()`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/text.html#docx.text.run.Run.add_picture) API.

Here is an example of its use:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document()

p = document.add_paragraph()
r = p.add_run()
r.add_text('Good Morning every body,This is my ')
r.add_picture('/tmp/foo.jpg')
r.add_text(' do you like it?')

document.save('demo.docx')
```

Comment: If you need to put a logo or watermark type image in the *header* of every page, you can now do that. See here: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/407

Comment: You can add after a paragraph using this:
paragraph._p.addnext(p._p)

Answer (score 16):

well, I don't know if this will apply to you but here is what I've done to set an image in a specific spot to a docx document:
I created a base docx document (template document). In this file, I've inserted some tables without borders, to be used as placeholders for images. When creating the document, first I open the template, and update the file creating the images inside the tables. So the code itself is not much different from your original code, the only difference is that I'm creating the paragraph and image inside a specific table.

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

doc = Document('addImage.docx')
tables = doc.tables
p = tables[0].rows[0].cells[0].add_paragraph()
r = p.add_run()
r.add_picture('resized.png',width=Inches(4.0), height=Inches(.7))
p = tables[1].rows[0].cells[0].add_paragraph()
r = p.add_run()
r.add_picture('teste.png',width=Inches(4.0), height=Inches(.7))
doc.save('addImage.docx')
```

Comment: For working in centimeters, simply replace the class Inches above by the class Cm !

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution. It has the advantage on the first proposition that it surrounds the picture with a title (with style Header 1) and a section for additional comments. Note that you have to do the insertions in the reverse order they appear in the Word document.

This snippet is particularly useful if you want to programmatically insert pictures in an existing document.

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

# ------- initial code -------

document = Document()

p = document.add_paragraph()
r = p.add_run()
r.add_text('Good Morning every body,This is my ')
picPath = 'D:/Development/Python/aa.png'
r.add_picture(picPath)
r.add_text(' do you like it?')

document.save('demo.docx')

# ------- improved code -------

document = Document()

p = document.add_paragraph('Picture bullet section', 'List Bullet')
p = p.insert_paragraph_before('')
r = p.add_run()
r.add_picture(picPath)
p = p.insert_paragraph_before('My picture title', 'Heading 1')

document.save('demo_better.docx')
```

Answer (score 2):

I spend few hours in it. If you need to add images to a template doc file using python, the best solution is to use python-docx-template library.
Documentation is available [here](https://docxtpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
Examples available in [here](https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template/tree/master/tests)

Answer (score 1):

This is variation on a theme. Letting I be the paragraph number in the specific document then:

```
p = doc.paragraphs[I].insert_paragraph_before('\n')
p.add_run().add_picture('Fig01.png', width=Cm(15))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is adopting the answer written by *Robᵩ* while considering more flexible input from user.
My assumption is that the HTML field mentioned by *Kais Dkhili* (orignal enquirer) is already loaded in `docx.Document()`. So...

#### Identify where is the related HTML text in the document.

```
import re 
## regex module

img_tag = re.compile(r'%\(profile_img\)s') # declare pattern

for _p in enumerate(document.paragraphs): 
    if bool(img_tag.match(_p.text)): 
        
        img_paragraph = _p 
        # if and only if; suggesting img_paragraph a list and 
        # use append method instead for full document search 
        
        break # lose the break if want full document search
```

#### Replace desired image into placeholder identified as `img_tag = '%(profile_img)s'`

The following code is after considering the text contains only a single `run`
May be changed accordingly if condition otherwise

```
temp_text = img_tag.split(img_paragraph.text)

img_paragraph.runs[0].text = temp_text[0] 

_r = img_paragraph.add_run()
_r.add_picture('profile_img.png', width = Inches(1.25))

img_paragraph.add_run(temp_text[1])
```

and done. `document.save()` it if finalised.

In case you are wondering what to expect from the `temp_text`...

`[In]`

```
img_tag.split(img_paragraph.text)
```

`[Out]`

```
['This is my ', ' do you like it?']
```