# Python docx table addrow() ignores my third row

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I would like to write an invoice with the latest version of python.
For that I have installed and imported the docx extension in the latest version.
I use this [Word document](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/58a8a1e58b69ad09cc1aaedf22b54bbf20201211211605/8a8f96) as a template and would like to add there a row at the table in the middle of this document.
The row with the text "Gesamtbetrag" should be the last row.

```
    import docx
    doc = docx.Document("Vorlage.docx")
    tabellen = []
    tables = doc.tables
    for table in tables:
        tabellen.append(table)
    row1 = tabellen[1].add_row()
```

This code adds a row which sits under my "Gesamtbetrag" row.
[Image of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjTd8.png)

But it should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXwP5.png).

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I don't follow any part of this question sorry

Comment: I have added an image of how the table should look like. Hopefully this can help you to understand my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the answer is that `add_row()` adds a row to the end of the table, and you have only one table.

I found this, which might be more of what you're looking for: [Possible to insert row at specific position with python-docx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215464/possible-to-insert-row-at-specific-position-with-python-docx)

Answer (score 0):

A have no idea how this tool works, but it's obvious that you just add a row to the second table ( `tabellen[1]` is a table ). And it does exactly what uou said - it adds row to the end of the table. Maybe you have to address a specific row, like `tabellen[1].insert_row(1)`, or `tabellen[1].add_row(1)` or whatever it uses to address a specific row position to add.