# Python - Insert pandas data frame in between of the document

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx, aspose.words

I have a `pandas` data frame which I want to insert in between of a `word document`. Let's say -

> - Section 1
>
> This is test word document
>
> *insert table here*
>
> - Section 2
>
> Table should be inserted before section 2.

Pandas data frame should be inserted in place of `insert table here`.

I checked `python-docx`, we can insert table very easily but that table will be inserted at the end of a document.

Can we insert table in between of the document using python-docx. If not, can someone suggest other library which I can use to achieve this functionality.

Comment: This question ([Add an image in a specific position in the document (.docx)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32932230/5358968)) addresses how to put a picture between text instead of just at the end - the same answers might carry over to your case?

Comment: Tried above approach, getting error message `table = r.add_table(rows=2, cols=3)
AttributeError: 'Run' object has no attribute 'add_table'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using Aspose.Words. In your case, you can insert bookmark as a placeholder where you need to insert a table and then use `DocumentBuilder` to insert table at the bookmark. For example see the following simple code:

```py
import aspose.words as aw

# Move cursor to the bookmark
builder.move_to_bookmark("table")

# build a table
builder.start_table()
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        builder.insert_cell()
        builder.write("Cell {0},{1}".format(i, j))
    builder.end_row()
builder.end_table()

doc.save("C:\\Temp\\out.docx")
```

Ass Aspose.Words for Python documentation to learn more about [working with bookmarks](https://docs.aspose.com/words/python-net/working-with-bookmarks/) and [working with tables](https://docs.aspose.com/words/python-net/working-with-tables/).

UPDATE: If you need to use a text as a placeholder, you can use code like the following:

```py
import aspose.words as aw

doc = aw.Document("C:\\Temp\\in.docx")
builder = aw.DocumentBuilder(doc)

# Search for a placeholder paragraph
paragraphs = doc.get_child_nodes(aw.NodeType.PARAGRAPH, True)
for para in paragraphs :
    paraText = para.to_string(aw.SaveFormat.TEXT).strip()
    if paraText == "insert table here":
        # Move cursor to the paragraph
        builder.move_to(para)
        # build a table
        builder.start_table()
        for i in range(5):
            for j in range(5):
                builder.insert_cell()
                builder.write("Cell {0},{1}".format(i, j))
            builder.end_row()
        builder.end_table()

        # If required you can remove the placeholder paragraph.
        para.remove()

# Save the result
doc.save("C:\\Temp\\out.docx")
```

In .NET and Java version of Aspose.Words you can use `IReplacingCallback` to achieve this, but in Python version this feature is not available yet. `IReplacingCallback` allows to perform a custom actions when `Range.Replace` action is performed.

Except table, you can insert content of another document, simply use DocumentBuilder.insert_document method. Code will look like this:

```py
# Move cursor to the paragrapg
builder.move_to(para)
# Insert conten of another document
builder.insert_document(aw.Document("C:\\Temp\\src.docx"),  aw.ImportFormatMode.KEEP_SOURCE_FORMATTING)
```

Comment: I have to add bookmark in the existing document. Consider above word example, bookmark is required in "insert table here". When I am using your code snippet, it is adding table in top of the document.

Comment: Awesome.. this is working fine. I have another requirement to copy content from another document and paste in specific position of a document, keeping the formatting intact. Suppose, we want to insert content of another document in place of "insert text here" and then create a table.

Comment: you can achieve this using DocumentBuilder.insert_document method. See the updated answer.